# Django Form Field for Dynamic Character Search

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Is there a django form field that allows for two widgets:

1. A text input for the search bar.
2. A list of elements of a query set that adjusts to each character entered into the search bar dynamically.

Kind of how the google search bar works, but the query set would be predefined to some Model for example.

The reason I would like this is that I would like users to enter, for example, 1 or 2 characters, and view all the possible elements of a query set that match those characters.

Is this a potential application for the RegexField?

Thank you

Comment: I personally use chosen plugin http://julesjanssen.github.io/chosen/. It only turns a normal dropdown into a searchable field, but your still use ChoiceField/ModelChoiceField in your django form.

Comment: Does this work with MySQL?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, but this plugin is a front-end only tool and doesn't involve in anything related to database. Without it you would get the form.ChoiceField rendered as a dropdown, and while installed, your dropdown becomes a searchable list as it's shown in their demo. As you type, it would show the matches and reduce the dropdown list. Please check the website first.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, but for some reason I am having a hard time getting it to work even though I have it installed, I have included the media,  I have added 'chosen' to installed apps, and I am implementing the ChosenModelChoiceField.

Comment: I'm not sure because I'm not using django-chosen, I just download the chosen package from https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ and use it in my javascript code. Just a guess, did you forget to include the chosen.css and chosen.js in your template?

Comment: well i have included chosen.css, chosen.jquery.min.js,  and chosen.jquery_ready.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84404/discussion-between-malonge-and-shang-wang).